# Better way to do a multi-join in this SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to pull data from a table (a.table) to join to another table (b.table). For me to do that, I need to join a third table (c.table) to reference between tables Plan_Code and Policy_Riders. Please see the code below

```
USE [CDS]
GO

SELECT riders.ExpiryDt--
      ,riders.TerminationDt
      ,[ModalPremium]--
      ,plan_code
  FROM a.table as riders

  JOIN c.table as policy
  ON policy.Policy_Num = riders.Policy_Num


 JOIN b.table AS plan_code
  on policy.Plan_Code_ID = plan_code.Plan_Code_ID

WHERE plan_code.Plan_Code LIKE '%EIUL3%' 
OR plan_code.Plan_Code LIKE '%LBIUL%'
OR plan_code.Plan_Code LIKE '%MEIUL3%'  
GO
```

For me to get the field name Plan_code from b.table to my output, I need to join first a.table to c.table, then c.table to b.table. My question is that is there a better way to approach this query to join better between the three tables? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: That looks to me like what you would have to do to get what you need.  If you are asking because it is slow, the LIKE '%value%' is slow and usually or clauses too.  If that is the case, you could try using UNION but probably not that much faster.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse! I wasn't sure if there was a more efficient way to do multiple joins in one select. Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: With your filter, it looks like `plan_code.Plan_Code LIKE '%EIUL3%'` would yield the results for `plan_code.Plan_Code LIKE '%MEIUL3%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, use a derived table for the filters:

```
...
JOIN (SELECT columns
      FROM b.table
      WHERE Plan_Code LIKE '%EIUL3%' 
         OR Plan_Code LIKE '%LBIUL%'
         OR Plan_Code LIKE '%MEIUL3%'
     ) AS plan_code ON policy.Plan_Code_ID = plan_code.Plan_Code_ID
```

This will generally make sure those filters are applied against the smallest set of data, instead of after all the tables are joined.  Another option would be to make the above a temp table, then join to it.  Same concept, just helping the optimizer work efficiently.  In smaller queries you'll see no difference, but in larger ones (especially those like this, with many filters from a single table) it will be night and day.

Second, your filters specifically.  Using a `LIKE` with front and back wildcards `%ex%` is not good.  It won't be able to use indexes.  Use one `ex%` or the other `%ex` if possible.

Other than that, your joins are fine and are the correct approach to getting columns from each table.